# Lightning Map Markers not getting populated

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, google-map

I have used lightning:map in one of my lightning component. It is working fine in my laptop but while opening the same in other laptops markers are not getting populated. I have checked location access also. All permissions are given. Please suggest how to resolve the same.

My Laptop
[image]

Other Laptops
[image]

Comment: Check in console if you are getting any error in them?

Comment: Hi, there is issue with lightning maps only.  In my code, I have set the markers list to blank and again populated markers in list in JS code. Then it started working fine.